# How to remove date and Time timestamp from a sentence using perl

Tags: perl

I want to remove the date and time (timestamp) form the content of the text as shown below.

```
IO ICD Difference Log Generated By:xyz
IO ICD Directory: C:\In_Wok_Tt\My_work\Testing\IO_ICD_DIFF_TOOL_C\IIDT_TEST_RES_ICD_SPEC_DIFF\data\TEST_IID_Rx0042_a
INFO 2021/05/06 14:06:45-A664 TX ICD Vs AVIO Comparison is started...
INFO 2021/05/06 14:06:45-Started parsing the A664 TX ICD File C:\In_Wok_Tt\My_work\Testing\IO_ICD_DIFF_TOOL_C\IIDT_TEST_RES_ICD_SPEC_DIFF\data\TEST_IID_Rx0042_a\GVII_A664TX_ICD.CSV
INFO 2021/05/06 14:06:45-IO ICD Program Load ID:PLID72
```

Comment: What have you tried? What issues are you having?

Comment: use regular expression (perle)[https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick]

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -i.old -pe 's#^(INFO )\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+(.*)$#$1$2#' log.txt
```

`-i.old` saves you by saving a backup of the file you are trying to process.

`(INFO )` matches the `INFO` tag and saves it into `$1`.

`\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+` matches the timestamp to be removed.

`(.*)` matches whatever may come after the timestamp and saves it into `$2`.

`$1$2` returns the `INFO` tag and the text that may come after the timestamp.

I hope that you are not trying to tamper with somebody else's logs.

Comment: `s#(?<=^INFO\s)\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}##gm`